# Scroll Tableview Cell with outer Scrollview instead of It's own scroll ?

Tags: ios, tableview

I have an Imageview covering half of the screen height and a tableview below it. Both are wrapped inside a UIScrollView. I want to scroll the whole view. Means inner scroll of tableview won't work and when I scroll, outer scroll will scroll image view up and then showing cells of tableview. At the end, Imageview will hide behind scroll and tableview content will take entire space. Can anybody tell me how to achieve this. ?

Thanks

Comment: This will help you out. https://michiganlabs.com/ios/development/2016/05/31/ios-animating-uitableview-header/ It's not the exact thing you want. But you can use it.

Comment: Simply disable the scroll of table view.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the outer scroll view(UIScrollView). Why don't you add only the inner table view and image view to where your outer scrollview is added. The image view can be added either above or below the table view. Let say your image view is below the table view then your image view will be covered by table view. In order to make it fully visible, set the talbview's content inset top to imageview's height and its background to clear color. then you can see both image and table view contents without one covering the other. The last thing you need to do is you have to handle the image view's y position when you scroll the table view so it looks like they are in the same scroll view. Use the scroll view delegate that is already available to you and play with scroll view's content offset and image view's y position.

I answered some similar question here with some sample code. [Hand off parent container's pan gesture to nested UICollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46246763/hand-off-parent-containers-pan-gesture-to-nested-uicollectionview/46373739#46373739)

It does with collection view but the main idea is same.